# Regex issue with mb_ereg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have this code which should remove non letter characters from a string:

```
<?php
$text = 'Random -text! and a word with many ppppps';
$text = mb_ereg_replace('[^\p{L} ]', ' ', $text);
echo $text;
?>
```

When I run it on localhost (php 5.6) returns what I expect:

```
Random text and a word with many ppppps
```

But on godaddy (php 5.3) it only returns:

```
ppppp
```

Seems to be something with the regexp `'[^\p{L} ]'` in `mb_ereg_replace` but I can't figure out what.

Comment: @AvinashRaj cannot use preg_replace because of foreign letters

Comment: Use [`$text = preg_replace('/[^\p{L} ]/u', ' ', $text);`](https://ideone.com/9ipHrM).

Comment: @stribizhev tried preg_replace but it removes Asian and other foreign letters too.

Comment: With `/u`? Then, I guess you need `$text = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M} ]/u', ' ', $text);`. Also, when you say *it does not work*, please provide exact samples that your code does not work well with. It will simplify testing and coming to the correct solution.

Comment: @stribizhev `$text = 'Random -text! and a japanese word アオサギ and one with many ppppps';
$text = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M} ]/u', ' ', $text);
echo $text;  ` works on localhost but on server returns 'ã‚¢ã‚ªã‚µã‚®' for foreign letters

Comment: Well, I tested at http://phptester.net with 5.3 setting, and `preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M} ]/u', ' ', $text);` works. No idea what can be a problem, but it is not the regex that is to blame. Are the PHP pages  saved with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: @stribizhev Added `ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');` and works fine. Thanks

Comment: By the way, `ereg_*` uses POSIX regular expression, which doesn't support `\p{L}` or Unicode properties. `ereg_*` functions are also deprecated - I don't know why you choose to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per you comment, it is clear that the godaddy server was not set to work with UTF8 encoding. So, after adding

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
```

you may use

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{M} ]/u', ' ', $text);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/9ipHrM) proving it works with UTF8.